# How do I correctly close shared channels in Goroutines while processing results

Tags: go, channel

I'm attempting to find the correct method of using results produced by worker go routines while also gracefully exiting the results loop when all the work is completed. To illustrate, I've made the following example. My real world case varies slightly from this example in that I don't know how much "work" each worker go routine will return, where as obviously these for loops are performing a fixed number of results (5).

I'm new to goroutines and channels, but the following are basic tenants as I understand them;

- Only senders should close a channel
- Performing `range` over a channel will continue until the channel is closed

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func worker1(r chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        r <- fmt.Sprintf("1.%d", i)
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func worker2(r chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        r <- fmt.Sprintf("2.%d", i)
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    r := make(chan string)
    wg.Add(2)
    go worker1(r, &wg)
    go worker2(r, &wg)

    for i := range r {
        fmt.Printf("Got job result: %s\n", i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

This example is deadlocking because the range loop never exits, as the channel never closes. I can perform a close on the channel once the work is done (i.e. replace `wg.Done()` with `close(r)`), but then I get a panic when the other worker goroutine attempts to send further results to the already closed channel.

Finally I figure I can move the `wg.Wait()` to above the results loop, close the channel once it has been completed, and then start printing results, but that implies I cannot print any results until all work has been completed on all threads.

*What is the correct way to gracefully exit the results loop once all worker threads have finished, while also not waiting until all of the work has been completed before beginning to print results?*

Comment: you `go func() { wg.Wait();close(r); }()`

Comment: Think of the `wg` WaitGroup as a counter for the *writer group*. You need some set of entities (collectively, "writers") that write to the channel and close it when done. To make that *easy*, you can have n (n==2 at the moment) "writers" that actually write, plus one extra non-writing "writer group member" that simply waits for the other writers to say "done" and then does the `close`. That's the anonymous function in mh-cbon's comment and Nick Corin's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've edited your code to work without deadlocks. The trouble is that receiving on the channel is blocking the main thread and neither of your two `goroutines` are sending any more data.

This solution runs a new `goroutine` which closes the results channel once the `WaitGroup` is done.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func worker1(r chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        r <- fmt.Sprintf("1.%d", i)
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func worker2(r chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        r <- fmt.Sprintf("2.%d", i)
    }

    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    r := make(chan string)
    wg.Add(2)
    go worker1(r, &wg)
    go worker2(r, &wg)

    go func() {
        defer close(r)
        wg.Wait()
    }()

    for i := range r {
        fmt.Printf("Got job result: %s\n", i)
    }
}
```

[(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.com/p/lC0mTi8gxbU)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn't think of something so basic. Appreciated, it all makes sense now.